# select non-existing data as null using HIVE LATERAL VIEW

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to get non existing data as null using outer explode in hive but my query is not returning anything.
EDIT :
Table - year string, companyrank

```
year:string,topcompanies:array<struct<name:string,rank:string>>
```

sample data
EDIT:

```
    2015,
  "topcompanies":[
  {"name":"apple","rank":"1"},
  {"name":"samsung","rank":"2"},
  {"name":"SONY","rank":"3"},
  ]

  2016,
  "topcompanies":[
  {"name":"apple","rank":"1"},
  {"name":"samsung","rank":"2"},
  {"name":"SONY","rank":"3"},
  {"name":"LG","rank":"4"}
  ]
```

query to get data

```
select  year, rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4
FROM companyrank
LATERAL VIEW outer explode(topcompanies) rank1_t as rank1_v
LATERAL VIEW outer explode(topcompanies) rank2_t as rank2_v
LATERAL VIEW outer explode(topcompanies) rank3_t as rank3_v
LATERAL VIEW outer explode(topcompanies) rank4_t as rank4_v
WHERE 
 (rank1_v.rank = 1 or rank1_v.rank is null)
 AND (rank2_v.rank = 2 or rank2_v.rank is null)
 AND (rank3_v.rank = 3 or rank3_v.rank is null)
 AND (rank4_v.rank = 4 or rank4_v.rank is null)
```

expected output-

```
expected output when rank4 does not exists
year  rank1 rank2   rank3   rank4
2016  apple samsung SONY    null
```

if rank4 data exists then

```
    year rank1  rank2   rank3   rank4
    2015 apple  samsung SONY    LG
```

EDIT:

I need to get all 4 ranks for each year, if any of the ranks does not exists then the rank should show NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward answer to your question is "use `lateral view outer`", but there is a much cleaner solution.

```
select      min (case when i.rank = 1 then i.name end)  as rank1
           ,min (case when i.rank = 2 then i.name end)  as rank2
           ,min (case when i.rank = 3 then i.name end)  as rank3
           ,min (case when i.rank = 4 then i.name end)  as rank4

from        companyrank c
            lateral view inline(topcompanies) i
;
```

---

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| rank1  |  rank2   | rank3  | rank4  |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| apple  | samsung  | SONY   | NULL   |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Dudu Markovitz... unfortunately I am running hive 0.14 and min is not supported "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 6:0 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'min'".
though I am using the lateral view outer explode but still unable to get the data when no value is there for rank4.

Comment: Try using a sub-query: `select min (case when i.rank = 1 then i.name end)  as rank1 ... from (select i.* from companyrank c lateral view inline(topcompanies) i) i
;`

Comment: Thanks Dudu .... it worked perfectly fine... just one concern is for performance...

Comment: Here we go again... :-) Do you think that with a reasonable optimizer, there is a performance difference between `select * from t` and `select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from ( select * from t) t) t) t) t) t;`?